# vue3 router - 2 routers with different history

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I need to have 2 routers one for the main view and one for the sidebar.
(sidebar is not a child of main view)

Sidebar router should be independent from the main router.
When we navigate one router the other do not react and vice versa.
And they both should have separted history `createMemoryHistory`
is it possible?

Comment: Everything is possible. You just need to invent it on your own.

Comment: Why you want separated history? All devices use single history.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You'll just will be unable to use things that are tied to current router instance like router comps and composables for one of them. Probably make sidebar a separate app for that

Comment: @EstusFlask but how it is done? is there any examples?

Comment: No specific examples, just common Vue knowledge. In case of the second option, use another createApp. Fwiw, I had a similar case with a sidebar and had to implement simple stack navigation instead of Vue router because it's really not well-suited for multiple instances